# How to identify ASP control between jQuery and code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have this to make an auto complete happen:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("input[type='text']").autocomplete();
    $("input[type='text']").keyup(function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('name');
        var params = {'id': id, 'partial': $this.val()};
        var jsonParams = JSON.stringify(params);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyPage.aspx/GetAutoCompleteList",
            data: jsonParams,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                $this.autocomplete('option','source', JSON.parse(msg.d));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and a way to call it:

```
[WebMethod]
public static String GetAutoCompleteList(string id, string partial)
{
    AutoCompleter completer;
    switch (id)
    {
        case "first-name":
            completer = first_names;
            break;
        case "last-name":
            completer = last_name;
            break;
        case "site":
            completer = site_numbers;
            break;
        case "institution":
            completer = institutions;
            break;
        // ....
        default:
            return "[]";
    }
    return jsSerializer.Serialize(toUse.CloseMatches(partial));
}
```

`AutoCompleter` just finds some potential matches and returns them as an array.

I'm running into a problem, because I'm not sure how to actually identify the inputs. Here's an example of one:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" name="first-name" id="first-name" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

BUT `$this.attr('name')` won't return `first-name`. It's instead some auto-generated ASP.NET nonsense. What's an easy way to definitively identify this input?

I mean, we could just do:

```
<div class="hacky" name="first-name" style="display:none"></div>
<asp:TextBox ... ></asp:TextBox>
```

and

```
var id = $this.siblings(".hacky").attr('name');
```

but there has to be an easier way.

Comment: Turn off ID mangle  generation or use ClientId in the code behind and Inject with data bound expression. The latter composes well with nested controls and Webforms.  The former with html/page-forward designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use static ID for your text input by adding:

> ClientIDMode = "Static"

2. If you have many, you can use static ID for all in the web.config
3. You can use some custom attribute like attr-data-id=(AspControll).ClientID